# Opções do Select2 somem ao selecionar uma

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Estou utilizando o Select2 para carregar dados remotamente e ele está trazendo os resultados normalmente, porém ao selecionar uma das opções retornadas todas as existentes somem e não consegui identificar o porquê, segue o código:

**Javascript**

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/Home/PopularUsuarios",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "post",
        delay: 250,
        theme: 'clasic',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                objPesquisa: params.term, // search term                              
            };
        },

        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            data.forEach(function (d, i) { d.id = i; })

            return {
                results: data,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: function (data) {
        if (data.loading) return data.text;
        var markup = '<option value="' + data.Matricula + '">' + data.Nome + '</option>'
        return markup;
    },
    templateSelection: function (data) {
        return data.full_name || data.text;
    }
});
```

Comment: Posta seu código http://www.codepen.io ou https://jsfiddle.net para que possamos entender melhor o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Em uma das partes do cadastro de atividades do sistema quero criar um campo no qual me permitirá selecionar o usuário associado a tal atividade, para tal utilizei o select2 que permite que eu digite o nome do funcionário, chama a função que cria uma lista de funcionários e retorna um JSON e apresenta o nome do funcionário, a lista está carregando sem problemas, ele consegue retornar os objeto também corretamente, mas na hora que eu clico um dos objetos (Supondo que existam 3 Marcos na empresa) todos os já listados desaparecem ao invés do drop down "recolher" e ficar com o clicado selecionado.